# I don't understand the "be done" part in this sentence. Please help

Tags: grammar

> That vocational education and all electives except foreign language ***be eliminated*** from the secondary curriculum was the proposal of a group led by Mortimer Huxley.

This is the sentence. I understand the meaning of it but I don't understand the grammar. So, the "be eliminated" part is a "be done". From my understanding, 'be done' is a form of main verb which means passive and the other form of passive, which is not the main verb, should be written like 'done', so it can be used in subject or object. But, in this sentence, 'be eliminated' is a part of subject. So what does this mean?

Comment: It's a subjunctive. Huxley's group proposed that [those things] _should be eliminated_ from the curriculum.

Comment: Is it easier to understand if I rephrase it like this: "*[The proposal the proposal of a group led by Mortimer Huxley] was [that vocational education be eliminated from the curriculum.]*" ? I have reversed the order of the two clauses largest clauses, and reduced the elements  to somewhat simpler versions without changing the grammar or reducing complexity. I've also put the [subject] and [subject complement] in brackets.

Comment: Ah, I see. I got go study the subjunctive. Many thanks.

Comment: So there is  a 'should' in front of the 'be eliminated'? But the writer didn't put it there because it is a subjunctive and it is not a clauses? Is this the correct understanding? Thanks.